# Using Random Once in a While loop

Tags: python, string, random

I'm having a bit of a problem using classes while using a random in a while loop. The goal is the first time to generate a random string and to use that throughout the lesson. Here are the four lines with the problem.

```
 def run_review(self, key_history):
        level = reviewer.ReviewLesson(self.history_list)
        if self.counter:
            level.shuffled()
            self.counter = False
            return shuffle
        level.review()
        level.review_lesson()
```

from another module

```
def shuffled(self):
        self.shuffled_list = sorted(self.history_list, key=lambda k: random.random())
        return self.shuffled_list

    def review(self): 
        for item in self.shuffled_list:
            self.word = item+self.word
        self.word = self.word*7
        return self.word


    def review_lesson(self):
        word = ''
        self.word = word+self.word
        return self.word
```

The issue is after the first block the review_lesson is an empty space since level.review() is not called, however if level.review is called it then becomes another random sequence.

**Edit**: Made the code a bit more clearer and removed duplicate functions.

Comment: move the random call outside the method also why are you adding an empty string to self.word and assigning self.word = ...  twice?

Comment: @poor coding for the second. The def run_review is a while loop that runs the loop for a pygame but as your suggestion I have edited as show:

Comment: `self.word + ""` is the same as just `self.word`, If you only want a single value just declare the  `shuffled_list ` as a class attribute like in my answeror an instance attribute depending on what you want. Then use it in the method, that way it will only be created once

Comment: you are indeed correct, my only problem is that self.history_list is it is define in the __init__ so now it won't let me define that.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, why can't you define it as an attribute?

Comment: history_list is not defined is the error or self.history_list is not define. Should I just make a new class that only does the shuffling.

Comment: you need to use `self.history_list = ...` in your init method and use `self.history_list ` to refer to it in the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assigning self.word to multiple things in your methods so not fully sure what that is doing  but to be able to use `review` and get the same random `shuffled_list` each time declare shuffled_list as a class attribute:

```
 # either declare before init, or use self.shuffled_list = .. in your init method
 shuffled_list = sorted(self.history_list, key=lambda k: random.random())

def review(self): 
        for item in class_name.shuffled_list:
            self.word = item+self.word
        self.word *= 7
        return self.word
```

For example:

```
 class Foo():
    r = randint(1, 7) # either here as class attribute so it will be the same for all instances
    def func(self):
        return  Foo.r

## -- End pasted text --

In [13]: for _ in range(5):
            f = Foo()
            print(f.func())
            f1 = Foo()
            print(f1.func())
   ....:     
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

A class attribute will keep it the same for all instances:

```
class Foo():
    r = randint(1, 7) 
    def func(self):
        return  Foo.r
```

If you wanted a different value for each instance  make it an instance attribute:

```
    class Foo():
        def __init__(self)
            self.r = randint(1, 7) 
        def func(self):
            return  self.r
```